# Modem Speed Limit

Tags: networking, internet-connection, modem, adsl, adsl2+

I changed my plan to a 4Mbps unlimited connection. But my download speed still shows 573Kbps in the ADSL settings webpage and I get slow download speed. I called the ISP's customer care and they said it is because of the modem's limit and that they would change my modem shortly. Well, "shortly" wasn't defined and I have been following up on this for one week. So, my question is, can I somehow upgrade my modem limit myself ?

1. Modem type : T-KD 318-MI
2. This is not illegal hacking as I will pay for my plan (4Mbps) anyhow.

ADSL settings image :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some modems need a hard-reset or reset to factory defaults to get them to re-download their settings from the ISP.

Usually this is done by holding a paperclip in a recessed button marked "reset" or similar. There may also be a button to press in the webpage setup for the device.

This will clear any settings you have changed such as the wifi network name but may force it to reset the data rate as well.

If it doesn't then the data rate needs to be properly set up on your ISPs side.

Comment: I tried as suggested but no effect.

Comment: From a quick google it seems as your modem is ADSL2+ (24MBps DL) so *it* should not be the cause of the slow speed. Conclusion: Probably a setting at your ISP.